# Linq equivalent for grouping select

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

From a traditional SQL sentence like this:

```
SELECT Id, Owner, MIN(CallTime) 
FROM traffic 
WHERE CallType = "IN" 
GROUP BY Owner;
```

where `CallTime` is a datetime field, what I want is the oldest record belonging to each `Owner`.

How can I achieve this with Linq?

This was my attempt (I'm using Entity Framework and `context` is the entity instance):

```
var query = context.traffic.Where(t => t.CallType == "IN");
var results = query
    .GroupBy(t => t.Owner)
    .Select(g => new { CallTime = g.Min(h => h.CallTime) });
```

But I need also access to `Id` and `Owner` fields whereas now I have only access to `CallTime`.

Comment: You can use [MinBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs)

Comment: Does your traditional SQL example actually run?

Comment: ANSI SQL does not permit using columns in the select list that are not part of `group by`; MySQL permits this (unless you run it in ANSI mode).

Comment: @AakashM Yes, because it's MySQL :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ahhh vendor-specific extensions :) which `Id` does it pick?

Comment: @AakashM [It is arbitrary chosen from among the eligible candidates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html). That's why it is useful only when all candidates are the same (e.g. group by ID, and add `name` and `address`).

Comment: @AakashM Yes it does, I don't need an specific Id but the oldest record (per Owner) based on CallTime field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access Id in the given code because you are grouping by Owner and the Key to the group will be the Owner not the 'traffic' object.

If you group by traffic objects you need some way to tell the groupBy how to compare them properly (i.e. group by owner) This can be done with an IEqualityComparer

e.g.

```
private class Traffic {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime CallTime { get; set; }
}

private class TrafficEquaityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Traffic> {
    public bool Equals(Traffic x, Traffic y) {
            return x.Owner == y.Owner;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Traffic obj) {
        return obj.Owner.GetHashCode();
    }
}


private static TrafficEquaityComparer TrafficEqCmp = new TrafficEquaityComparer();

private Traffic[] src = new Traffic[]{
   new Traffic{Id = 1, Owner = "A", CallTime = new DateTime(2012,1,1)},  // oldest
   new Traffic{Id = 2, Owner = "A", CallTime = new DateTime(2012,2,1)},
   new Traffic{Id = 3, Owner = "A", CallTime = new DateTime(2012,3,1)},
   new Traffic{Id = 4, Owner = "B", CallTime = new DateTime(2011,3,1)},
   new Traffic{Id = 5, Owner = "B", CallTime = new DateTime(2011,1,1)},   //oldest
   new Traffic{Id = 6, Owner = "B", CallTime = new DateTime(2011,2,1)},
};

[TestMethod]
public void GetMinCalls() {
     var results = src.GroupBy(ts => ts, TrafficEqCmp)
                        .Select(grp => {
                            var oldest = grp.OrderBy(g => g.CallTime).First();
                            return new { Id = oldest.Id, 
                                         Owner = grp.Key.Owner, 
                                         CallTime = oldest.CallTime };

                        });    }
```

this gives

```
ID : Owner : MinCallTime

1 :    A   :  (01/01/2012 00:00:00)
5 :    B   :  (01/01/2011 00:00:00)
```

as the results.

Comment: Thats exactly what I need but unfortunately the Entity Framework doesn't seem to like the GroupBy customization as it launchs a very long error message: LINQ to Entities does not recognize method System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[ns.traffic,ns.traffic]] GroupBy[traffic,traffic](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ns.traffic], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ns.traffic,ns.traffic]], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[ns.traffic])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store."}

Comment: @JPG Nope, it is not going to like it but, if you are not worried about running the query on the DB, you can try 'var query = context.traffic.Where(t => t.CallType == "IN").ToList();'.  This should force the query to be resolved and you can run the group by on the resulting list.

Comment: Ok, that would be possible, howerver I think your code does not work fine as it returns an unrelated Id. For Owner 'B' it returns Id=4 instead of Id=5, CallTime is fine though.

Comment: @JPG Yep, I my bad. I was too focused on getting the date correct. The new version gives the correct id.  I should have written a better test first time around :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works as intended. I can't vote your answer due to my low reputation :(

Comment: Based on your answer I've simplified it a little bit removing the IEqualityComparer and returning a Traffic object:
var results = src.GroupBy(ts => ts.Owner).Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(g => g.CallTime).First());
Would you mind to give me your comments? I'm not sure but seems to return correct results.

Comment: @JPG, yep, this will work (and better than my idea). It gives the Key as the owner, but all the details are in the group (which is an IEnumerable<Traffic>), so once we grab the first entry we will have the min time and ID. Simpler to code and understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL query doesn't look valid to me: you're using `Id` but not grouping by it. I assume that you wanted to group by `Id` and `Owner`?

```
var results = query
     .GroupBy(t => new {Id = t.Id, Owner = t.Owner})
     .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key.Id, Owner = g.Key.Owner, CallTime = g.Min(h => h.CallTime) })
     .ToList();
```

If you want to get the oldest (smallest) `ID` instead of grouping by it:

```
var results = query
     .GroupBy(t => t.Owner)
     .Select(g => new { Id = g.Min(x => x.Id), Owner = g.Key, CallTime = g.Min(h => h.CallTime) })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: If I group by Id then the result contains several records per Owner while I need the oldest (only one) record from each Owner based on CallTime field.

Comment: I could imagine both scenarios (`Id` same for same `Owner` or `Id` unique). Changed my answer to reflect this other option, as it better fits @JPG's needs

Comment: @Zruty, Almost! I would need not the smallest Id but the Id (and Owner) of Min(CallTime).

Answer (score 0):

// `custQuery` is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Customer>>`

```
var custQuery =  
    from cust in customers  
    group cust by cust.City into custGroup  
    where custGroup.Count() > 2  
    orderby custGroup.Key  
    select custGroup;
```

In that example you select the group